# Uniform random variable is greater by a constant from another uniform random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, uniform-distribution

I am trying to formulate the following question. 
X and Y are IID , uniform r.v. with ~U(0,1)

What is the probability of
P( X-Y-0.5 > 0) = ?

0.5 is a constant here and can be different.

I do respect the geometrical solutions but what i would like to see and understand is the generic approach since X and Y can be other distributions.

Comment: Yes they are IID. I will add the tag. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of calculation is in general handled with using the **joint** distribution of the two variables $X$ and $Y$.

You state that $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. $U(0, 1)$'s, and this uniquely specifies their joint distribution. Since they are independent, the joint density function factors:

$$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) = 1 \times 1 = 1$$

Given this, you can calculate any probability involving $X$ and $Y$ by integrating this joint distribution over the region specified in the probability:

$$P(X - Y > 0.5) = \int_{x - y > 0.5} f(x, y) \ dx dy = \int_{x - y > 0.5} 1 \ dx dy = \frac{1}{4}$$

In this case it's relatively easy to evaluate this integral by inspection, for more complicated cases evaluating the integral may take some work and creativity.

Comment: @mathew Thanks. How did the last part of the integral expanded ? I was expecting 2 integrals instead of 1. Also can you show explicitly lower-upper bounds of calculation.

Comment: BTW the answer is 1/4 not 1/2. I am trying to understand the whole steps though.

Comment: Yah, y'all are right. Sorry people, seems like my thoughts were a bit muddy.

Comment: @math_law It is a double integral when you calculate it with Fubini's theorem. I'm just writing it as an integral over a region on the plane.

Answer (score 2):

The generic approach is to find the distribution of the rv $X-Y$, denoted $Z$, from the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, which is a convolution exercise. Since the change of variables from $(X,Y)$ to $(Z=X-Y,Y)$ has Jacobian one
$$\left|\dfrac{\text d(x,y)}{\text d(z,y)}\right|=\left|\dfrac{\text d(z+y,y)}{\text d(z,y)}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}1 &1\\0 &1\\\end{matrix}\right|=1$$
the joint distribution of $(Z,Y)$ has density$$f_{Z,Y}(z,y)=f_{X,Y}(z+y,y)$$and the marginal distribution of $Z$ has density$$f_Z(z)=\int_{\mathcal Y}f_{X,Y}(z+y,y)\text dy$$leading to$$\mathbb{P}(Z>z_0)=\int_{z_0}^\infty \int_{\mathcal Y}f_{X,Y}(z+y,y)\text dy\, \text dz$$
as for instance
$$\mathbb{P}(Z>0.5)=\int_{0.5}^1\int_{0}^1 \mathbb I_{(0,1)}(y+z)\text dy\, \text dz$$
for two iid $U(0,1)$ rvs. Leading to
$$\mathbb{P}(Z>0.5)=\int_{0.5}^1\int_{0}^{1-z} \mathbb I_{(0,1)}(y+z)\text dy\, \text dz=\int_{0.5}^1 (1-z)\, \text dz=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: How do you apply the formulae to this question ? How do you use the constant 0.5. and get the result ? (Note this is not homeworkd)

Comment: Very well explained Xi'an , thank you !

Comment: And this is a very good reference for the concept. https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/sums-of-independent-random-variables

Comment: Ha. This is way better than my answer!

Comment: PS: Final answer has a basic calculation error. The result of the integral is 1/8 instead. My bad. Thank you.

Comment: The change of variable Z is not required here. Just double integrals over regions X and Y. The boundraies are (0 to 1-z)-inner and (0.5 to 1)-outer